# Guice Novice Error in Using AemLogin of Bobcat through my Java main

Tags: selenium, dependency-injection, guice-3

I am new to Bobcat(automated framework for AEM).I am trying to write a sample Java class that could use the AemLogin API through a inject.But I am getting errors. I am unable to clearly understand how to use the Module to bind since there is only one implementation class of AemLogin that i am trying to inject.

```
import com.cognifide.qa.bb.aem.AemLogin;
   import com.google.inject.Guice;
   import com.google.inject.Inject;
   import com.google.inject.Injector;

   public class BobcatMain {
    @Inject
    private LoginTest loginTest;

    private static  String url ="localhost:4502";
    private static String login ="admin";
    private static String password ="admin";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
        injector.getInstance(BobcatTest.class).AuthenticateUser();

    }
}

import com.cognifide.qa.bb.aem.AemLogin;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.name.Named;
public class BobcatTest {
    private static  String url ="localhost:4502";
    private static String login ="admin";
    private static String password ="admin";
    private AemLogin aemLogin;

    @Inject
    public BobcatTest(AemLogin aem) {
        this.aemLogin= aem;
         System.out.println(aem);
    }
        public void AuthenticateUser() {
            aemLogin.login(url, login, password);
            System.out.println("Login Successful");
        }
}
```

When i run the application i get multiple errors

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
```

1) No scope is bound to com.cognifide.qa.bb.guice.ThreadScoped.
  at com.cognifide.qa.bb.aem.AemAuthCookieFactory.class(AemAuthCookieFactory.java:51)
  while locating com.cognifide.qa.bb.aem.AemAuthCookieFactory
2) No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=author.login) was bound.
  while locating java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=author.login)
3) No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=author.password) was bound.
  while locating java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=author.password)
4) No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=author.url) was bound.
  while locating java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=author.url)
 5) No implementation for org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver was bound.
  while locating org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

5 errors
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1004)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at com.test.diageo.BobcatMain.main(BobcatMain.java:19)